# Компрессия изображения с минимальными потерями качества

Tags: xcode, swift, изображения, compression

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане!
Стоит уточнить, что с языком программирования Swift и со всеми его составляющими я знаком три дня!
Три дня пытаюсь решить данную проблему, ни одного решения не нашел, перерыл очень много сайтов! Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы изображения при выгрузке на сервер весело не больше 150 кб, но при этом, чтобы качество было хорошее.
За время поисков нашел алгоритм, на сайтах и на GitHub'е писали, что это копия сжатия изображения месенджера WhatsApp, но на iphone 8 он очень не качественно сжимает изображение. Если приводить пример, то сжатие сфотографированного изображения на iphone 8 при передаче по месенджеру WhatsApp сжимается до 100 кб., при этом качество изображения очень хорошее, а длина и ширина больше 1000px. А если использовать этот алгоритм, то при длине:800px и ширине:600px и коэффициентом сжатия 0.01 изображение весит больше 200 кб. и качество ужасное .
Вот этот алгоритм:

```
extension UIImage {
func compressImage() -> UIImage? {
    // Reducing file size to a 10th
    var actualHeight: CGFloat = self.size.height
    var actualWidth: CGFloat = self.size.width
    let maxHeight: CGFloat = 800.0
    let maxWidth: CGFloat = 600.0
    var imgRatio: CGFloat = actualWidth/actualHeight
    let maxRatio: CGFloat = maxWidth/maxHeight
    var compressionQuality: CGFloat = 0.01

    if actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth {
        if imgRatio < maxRatio {
            //adjust width according to maxHeight
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth
            actualHeight = maxHeight
        } else if imgRatio > maxRatio {
            //adjust height according to maxWidth
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight
            actualWidth = maxWidth
        } else {
            actualHeight = maxHeight
            actualWidth = maxWidth
            //compressionQuality = 1
        }
    }
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: actualWidth, height: actualHeight)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    self.draw(in: rect)
    guard let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
        return nil
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, compressionQuality) else {
        return nil
    }
    return UIImage(data: imageData)
}
```

}

Как так с этим алгоритмом ничего не получилось, я стал искать библиотеки сжатия изображения на Swift, но ничего путного, к сожалению, я не нашел! Потом я попытался использовать алгоритм сжатия LZFSE, но как я понял, без декомпрессора на другом устройстве(предположим с ОС Android) изображение не будет отображено, к тому же он в одной из строк кода жаловался на nil-данных.
Вот код:

```
    public enum CompressionAlgorithm {
  case lz4   // speed is critical
  case lz4a  // space is critical
  case zlib  // reasonable speed and space
  case lzfse // better speed and space
}

private enum CompressionOperation {
  case compression, decompression
}

private func perform(_ operation: CompressionOperation,
                     on input: Data,
                     using algorithm: CompressionAlgorithm,
                     workingBufferSize: Int = 2000) -> Data?  {
  var output = Data()

  // set the algorithm
  let streamAlgorithm: compression_algorithm
  switch algorithm {
    case .lz4:   streamAlgorithm = COMPRESSION_LZ4
    case .lz4a:  streamAlgorithm = COMPRESSION_LZMA
    case .zlib:  streamAlgorithm = COMPRESSION_ZLIB
    case .lzfse: streamAlgorithm = COMPRESSION_LZFSE
  }

  // set the stream operation, and flags
  let streamOperation: compression_stream_operation
  let flags: Int32
  switch operation {
    case .compression:
      streamOperation = COMPRESSION_STREAM_ENCODE
      flags = Int32(COMPRESSION_STREAM_FINALIZE.rawValue)
    case .decompression:
      streamOperation = COMPRESSION_STREAM_DECODE
      flags = 0
  }

  // create a stream
  var streamPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<compression_stream>
    .allocate(capacity: 1)
  defer {
    streamPointer.deallocate(capacity: 1)
  }

  // initialize the stream
  var stream = streamPointer.pointee
  var status = compression_stream_init(&stream, streamOperation, streamAlgorithm)
  guard status != COMPRESSION_STATUS_ERROR else {
    return nil
  }
  defer {
    compression_stream_destroy(&stream)
  }

  // set up a destination buffer
  let dstSize = workingBufferSize
  let dstPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: dstSize)
  defer {
    dstPointer.deallocate(capacity: dstSize)
  }

  // process the input
  return input.withUnsafeBytes { (srcPointer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in

    stream.src_ptr = srcPointer
    stream.src_size = input.count
    stream.dst_ptr = dstPointer
    stream.dst_size = dstSize

    while status == COMPRESSION_STATUS_OK {
      // process the stream
      status = compression_stream_process(&stream, flags)

      // collect bytes from the stream and reset
      switch status {

      case COMPRESSION_STATUS_OK:
        output.append(dstPointer, count: dstSize)
        stream.dst_ptr = dstPointer
        stream.dst_size = dstSize

      case COMPRESSION_STATUS_ERROR:
        return nil

      case COMPRESSION_STATUS_END:
        output.append(dstPointer, count: stream.dst_ptr - dstPointer)

      default:
        fatalError()
      }
    }
    return output
  }
}

// Compressed keeps the compressed data and the algorithm
// together as one unit, so you never forget how the data was
// compressed.  
public struct Compressed {
  public let data: Data
  public let algorithm: CompressionAlgorithm

  public init(data: Data, algorithm: CompressionAlgorithm) {
    self.data = data
    self.algorithm = algorithm
  }

  // Compress the input with the specified algorithm. Returns nil if it fails.
  public static func compress(input: Data,
                              with algorithm: CompressionAlgorithm) -> Compressed? {
    guard let data = perform(.compression, on: input, using: algorithm) else {
      return nil
    }
    return Compressed(data: data, algorithm: algorithm)
  }

  // Factory method to return uncompressed data. Returns nil if it cannot be decompressed.
  public func makeDecompressed() -> Data? {
    return perform(.decompression, on: data, using: algorithm)
  }
}

// For discoverability, add a compressed method to Data
extension Data {
  // Factory method to make compressed data or nil if it fails.
  public func makeCompressed(with algorithm: CompressionAlgorithm) -> Compressed? {
    return Compressed.compress(input: self, with: algorithm)
  }
}
```

Вот в этой строке, после применения этого алгоритма:

```
UIImage(data: imageCompressData)//к переменной imageCompressData был применен код сверху!
```

Далее я случайно наткнулся на этот код:

```
func resizeImageUsingVImage(image:UIImage, size:CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    let cgImage = image.cgImage!
    var format = vImage_CGImageFormat(bitsPerComponent: 8, bitsPerPixel: 32, colorSpace: nil, bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.first.rawValue), version: 0, decode: nil, renderingIntent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)
    var sourceBuffer = vImage_Buffer()
    defer {
        free(sourceBuffer.data)
    }
    var error = vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage(&sourceBuffer, &format, nil, cgImage, numericCast(kvImageNoFlags))
    guard error == kvImageNoError else { return nil }
    // create a destination buffer
    let scale = image.scale
    let destWidth = Int(size.width)
    let destHeight = Int(size.height)
    let bytesPerPixel = image.cgImage!.bitsPerPixel/8
    let destBytesPerRow = destWidth * bytesPerPixel
    let destData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: destHeight * destBytesPerRow)
    defer {
        destData.deallocate(capacity: destHeight * destBytesPerRow)
    }
    var destBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: destData, height: vImagePixelCount(destHeight), width: vImagePixelCount(destWidth), rowBytes: destBytesPerRow)
    // scale the image
    error = vImageScale_ARGB8888(&sourceBuffer, &destBuffer, nil, numericCast(kvImageHighQualityResampling))
    guard error == kvImageNoError else { return nil }
    // create a CGImage from vImage_Buffer
    var destCGImage = vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer(&destBuffer, &format, nil, nil, numericCast(kvImageNoFlags), &error)?.takeRetainedValue()
    guard error == kvImageNoError else { return nil }
    // create a UIImage
    let resizedImage = destCGImage.flatMap { UIImage(cgImage: $0, scale: 0.0, orientation: image.imageOrientation) }
    destCGImage = nil
    return resizedImage
}
```

Немного детальнее присмотревшись к коду и изучив документацию по vImage, и библиотеки Accelerate я понял, что эта очень мощная библиотека обработки изображений, если бы у меня хватало знаний, возможно я бы смог создать хороший компрессор изображений, но знаний моих недостаточно, поэтому вся надежда на Вас.